# How do you use native Knockout templates with the KO external template engine

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, knockout-templating

I am using the KO external template engine to break down my single page webapp into multiple files, but the templates I am loading only contain KO markup.

Despite researching the topic extensively I can't figure out how to reliably apply KO bindings to the templates that are being loaded.

The key points are that:

- The DOM elements defined by the template don't exist initially
- My template bindings are dynamic, so I don't that KO will request the templates when applying bindings to the whole document
- I don't want to  make the template loading synchronous
- The pb is made even more tricky by the fact that infuser, that some template caching may be occurring which is causing KO to complain that I am applying the bindings twice.

This is is the code I have, which has at least two issues:

- There is no guarantee that the template has finished loading as I am calling applyBindings
- KO complains that I am trying to reapply bindings when I navigate back and forth

Any suggestion for a clean, reliable method of applying bindings once and only once to external template nodes as they are being added to the DOM?

- In *index.html*:

  ```
  <div id="templateDiv" data-bind="template: { name: currentView() }"></div>
  ```
- In *main.js*:

  ```
  function AdminViewModel() {
       var self = this;
       self.currentView = ko.observable('adminHome');
   }

  var viewModel = new AdminViewModel();

  var SammyApp = $.sammy('#admin_content', function() {
    //...
    this.get('#/editMembers', function(context) {
        viewModel.currentView('editMembers');
        ko.applyBindings(viewModel, $('.ko-template').get(0));
    });
  };

  ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
  ```

Answer (score 1):

if i got you point then you can do this

load you template in one base file in js using get and assign to script tag as below

```
var script   = document.createElement("script");
               script.id  = "YourTemplateName";
               script.type  = "text/html";
               script.text  = result.Value; //template data
               document.body.appendChild(script);
```

and in your index/base html file assign template

```
<div id="OtherTemplateDiv" data-bind="template: { name: 'YourTemplateName' }">
            </div>
```

Comment: Well, I have that part figured out. The problem is with an external template that is being loaded waaay after the initial call to applyBindings is made (say after 15mn of navigation through the app the user suddenly navigates to a view that loads a new template).

Comment: try something  like this ko.applyBindings(objectLateLoaded, $("#DivIdInWhichTemplateAdded")[0]);

Answer (score 0):

This is not a solution on how to use the templates, but this is how I split into files using the **[with binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/with-binding.html)**.

Suppose you have a page like this:

```
<div data-bind="with: block1">
    <input data-bind="value: yourFirstInput" />
    <!-- more markeup -->
</div>
<div data-bind="with: block2">
    <select data-bind="options: dropDownlist2options"></select>
    <!-- more markeup -->
</div>
```

You can put the `block1` in a file (I use `ascx`), `block2` in another file. 
 Then in your viewmodel you have something like:

```
var viewmodel = function () {
    var self = this;
    this.block1 = ko.observable();
    this.block2 = ko.observable();
}
var vm = new viewmodel();
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

This way you applyBindings on the whole page. The `with binding` will handle the check for null/undefined objects and display the blocks only when the obects are instanciated.

You can then do something like this when you want to display `block1`:

```
vm.block1({ yourFirstInput: ko.observable('aa')});
```

Actually I do that with the mapping plugin, this is just an example.

**[Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GabrielTran/V27QG/1/)** (notice how the block1 appears after the setTimeout)

Comment: Hmmm, the problem is that I could have over 50 external templates, so I don't want to load them all before calling applyBindings(). Your fiddle works because all the DOM nodes (main document and all templates) are created before applyBindings is called, isn't it?

Comment: Actually what matters is to define the blocks before calling applyBindings on the related DOM elements. You can load the markup after but you will have to call applyBindings on it (ko.Applybindings(vm, domElement))

Answer (score 0):

I have made a Template engine for KO

https://github.com/AndersMalmgren/Knockout.Bootstrap.TemplateStore/wiki

It requires a Owin enabled web server, once configured it understands that a ViewModel named `FooViewModel` should be connected to the View called `FooView`

Install using nuget (For ASP.NET)

```
Install-Package Knockout.Bootstrap.TemplateStore.SystemWeb
```

It is also designed to be easy to use in a SPA

Demo
https://github.com/AndersMalmgren/Knockout.Bootstrap.Demo

Answer (score 0):

I came up with something that works using an afterRender callback... although a bit messy IMHO, improvements welcome.

The afterRender callback is invoked twice for some reason, the second time around with an empty object, hence the test for hasOwnProperty('nodeType').

isBound() checks if the bindings have already been applied to the element - an attempt to add a custom marker CSS ('ko-applied') class to the element after the applying the bindings didn't work reliably.

Not sure that copying the koElements array is actually needed, but without that I have ended up with undefined elements[i] in the loop, so the template loader may be asynchronously updating the array while afterRender is running.

```
<div id="templateDiv" data-bind="template: { name: currentView(), afterRender: applyTemplateBindings }"></div>

self.applyTemplateBindings = function(koElements) {
            var elements = koElements.slice();
            for (var i = 0, len = elements.length; i < len; i++) {
                var element = elements[i];
                if (element.hasOwnProperty('nodeType') && ! $(element).hasClass('infuser-loading') &&
                    ! isBound(element)) {
                    ko.applyBindings(self, element);
                }
            }
        };

        var isBound = function(node) {
            return !!ko.dataFor(node);
        };
```